# Node.js APIドキュメントの関数シグネチャの表記方法

Tags: node.js

Node.jsのAPIドキュメントで、関数シグネチャを表現する際は以下のような表記が出てきます。

> ```
> Buffer.from(object[, offsetOrEncoding[, length]])
> ```

※objectは必須、offsetOrEncoding・lengthはオプション、lengthを指定する場合はoffsetOrEncodingの指定が必要と理解しています。

この表記方法は公式に定義されているものなのでしょうか？

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/74c3rczmf9ohul) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)